# Is it okay to have my function to both display an error message and return a boolean value?

Tags: java, exception

I am creating a function that returns true or false if some kind of error exists. Currently, if an error occurs a pop up is displayed with the error and the function returns false. If there is no error, then it just returns true.

My question is this:
Is it okay that my method both returns a boolean and displays a pop up, OR should I just have my method return a value (either an int or boolean) and then based on that return value display an error message if needed?

Here is an example if it helps:

```
private boolean correctFormat() {

 if (error1) {
  //display pop up for error1
 } else if (error2) {
  //display pop up for error2
 }
 ...
 else {
  return true;
 } //no errors

 return false; //there was an error
}
```

Other option:

```
private int correctFormat() {

 if (error1) {
  return 1;
 } else if (error2) {
  return 2;
 }
 ...
 else {
  return 0;
 } //no error
}

private void checkFormat() {

 int result = correctFormat();

 if (result == 1) {} //display pop up for error1
 else if (result == 2) {} //display pop up for error2
 ...
 else {} //result == 0, no error, do nothing
}
```

Comment: This belongs in the stackexchange site called something with "review".

Comment: It is fine. If you woudn't do that you wouldn't be able to check which error happened. The second solution is standard errorcode solution which is OK too. In some cases though, you could use exceptions for error handling.

Comment: It may not be the proper design to handle the exception in the function that generates it.  If that is the case, you must return a value with more information (such as an integer error code).

Comment: @MateuszDryzek Is one preferred over the other?

Comment: @ NickMiller So the 2nd option is the better way to go?

Comment: @bobdylan Depends on what you want to do really, if you need to know which error happened return the errorcode (or throw specific exception), if all you need to know is whether the error happened or not you can use boolean

Comment: @ MateuszDryzek Okay, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use exceptions to communicate error conditions rather than returning a boolean:

1. If you forget to use a return value, neither the compiler nor the runtime will complain, and your program will not work without telling the user why. If you forget to handle an exception, the runtime will complain, and if it is a checked exception, you'll even get an error at compile time.
2. Unlike a boolean, an exception can communicate *which* error occurred.
3. Unlike a boolean, an exception can communicate the *consequences* of a failure ("caused by ...").

Further reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html

You should not inform both the caller and the user about an exception, lest your caller inform the user a second time. I have worked on systems that reported the same error no less than 4 times due to this. Every exception should be reported once and only once.